# How to create IPv6 port group on vSwitch VMware ESXi 6.5

Tags: networking, ipv6, vmware-vsphere, vswitch

I was wondering how to create a IPv6 port group on a vSwitch in ESXi 6.5.

I have IPV6 enabled on all the hosts in my cluster, and when creating the port group it does not ask me if it is IPv6 or not. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: Why would you expect the creation of a port group to ask if if it IPv6 or not?

Answer (score 7):

The key here is the word 'switch', if you're using a VSS or DVS then that's what you've got - a switch, a layer-2 only device, i.e. it doesn't care a jot about what layer-3 protocol you're using - it doesn't know if you're using IP or not - so whether you're using IPv4 or v6, or any other L3 protocol (they do exist) then the switch won't care, it'll forward ethernet packets all day long and not care about what's in them while it's doing it.

Comment: Got it, so if i assign that port group to a VM, and configure ipv6 in that VM, it will be ok?

Comment: @RyanMendoza The vSwitch will not care. That's not to say you won't have any problems with IPv6, but if you do have a problem, it won't be because of the vSwitch.